# Monadic second-order theories of the reals

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

I’m looking for a survey of monadic second-order theories of the reals.

I’m starting from a 1985 [survey](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~gurevich/Opera/64.pdf) by Gurevich which says (p 505) that true arithmetic can be *reduced* to “the monadic theory of the real line” even though true arithmetic can not be *interpreted* in that theory.  But which monadic theory does he mean?  And is there a good reference for the latter claim, for which he cites a 1981 preprint with Shelah?

I think he means the theory in the language with two predicates, one for inclusion and one for openness of subsets. In any case I’d like a reference that covers monadic second-order theories with < and + as well.

Most work on monadic second-order logic seems to focus on orders and trees, which makes it harder to find what I’m looking for. Is there a good reference on monadic second-order theories of the reals from more recently than 1985?

Comment: This [paper](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~gurevich/Opera/79.pdf) by Gurevich and Shelah seems to be relevant.

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan, thanks, that paper gives the precise statement I was looking for! But it gives the proof with no outline and no other assistance for the reader.

Comment: Lifsches and Shelah have a more recent and more readable overview for that particular claim in "Peano Arithmetic may not be interpretable in the monadic theory of linear orders", J Symbolic Logic 62 (1997) 848-872, on JSTOR (https://jstor.org/stable/2275575) or on Shelah's site (http://shelah.logic.at/short400.html) as paper 471.